# Why hibernate validation breaks compilation with lombok dependency?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, lombok

Here is POJO with lombock (version 1.16.22) sample:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)    
public MyClass {
    private final Long id;    
}
```

Here everything works perfect. But after hibernate validator is added to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I got exception during maven **compilation** process:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project my-impl: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:      
[ERROR] /C:/path/MyClass.java:[12,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class MyClassBuilder
[ERROR] location: class my_package.MyClass
```

1. How and why hibernate validation affects lombock?
2. How fix this?

Comment: It's the validator annotation processor. You have an ordering problem... Also, could you run your question through a spell checker? Pretty please?

Comment: This error is not related to hibernate validator. Try performing maven clean build with and without validator. Reply if the error still exists.

Comment: I have already done this. And error still here.

Comment: `You have an ordering problem` - and how customize ordering?

Comment: place annotation processor dependency before hibernate validator in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm specifying that Lombok annotation processor should be used before MapStruct processor:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.20</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=cdi
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I think that in a similar way you can specify an ordering for Lombok and Hibernate Validator.

I think that this is what you need:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.22</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: BTW, you can use Hibernate Validator without the annotation processor. It's just a convenient way to check your constraints make sense but it's not required at all.